# Are there any openly available simulators describing how planets form from protoplanetary disk?

Tags: planetary-formation, n-body-simulations

Out of pure interest, I wonder whether there are existing open-source simulators that can simulate the formation of stars and planets from a protostar and the surrounding protoplanetary disk?

Comment: I would also be very interested in the answer to this question. @uhoh I am sure you would know some related questions, do you? Maybe you could give us some other hints, please?